# low beam does not work, daytime running and high beam do

Tags: honda, headlight, crv

I have a 2009 Honda CRV with a driver's side low beam that does not work, but yet the daytime running and high beam does work.  The passenger side is fine.  I checked the low beam, driver's side, fuse underneath the steering column and it does not seem to be the problem.  Not sure if the filament for DRL/high beam is one and low beam another.  Any suggestions or does it just simply need a new bulb?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most vehicles not using an LED headlight have multiple filaments in the bulb. These frequently do burn out independently. Low beam is also the most used filament, and likely to burn out first.

Given no fuses are blown or wires loose, it's most likely just a bad bulb.
Bulbs are generally pretty cheap, a few dollars, so it's worth just replacing it just in case.

A blown fuse would more likely take out both headlights.

Comment: Go to a parts store and have them sell you the right bulb. They are used to troubleshooting these simple issues and giving you the right parts. Some even install it for free.